# Getting an Audiostream to work in Java, Getting Malformed URL Exception

Tags: java, audio, streaming, multimedia

So I have this class which does not appear to work for whatever reason, it is giving me a Malformed URL exception but I can't find any reason the URL shouldn't be valid.

```
public static void nyan()
{
    String soundfile = "http://api.ning.com/files/3zmSvhA*3jKxFJj1I5uh5dp5oCynyyMksQjwS3JWWQNlriTzDzX61KtlFnuQtx-hEmV7NdqVgofmZvh7cXOX-UVJ47m1SR4a/nyanlooped.mp3";
    URL url = new URL(soundfile);

    AudioStream as = new AudioStream (url.openStream());
    AudioData data = as.getData();
    ContinuousAudioDataStream cas = new ContinuousAudioDataStream (data);
    AudioPlayer.player.start(cas);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, it's probably something simple, thanks

Answer (score 0):

What version of Java are you using? I can very well create a URL from `URL url = new URL(soundfile);` using Java 6. The URL is fine, it does not contain any unsafe characters, at least not the one that you posted here.

But here's my guess: The example you posted was not the one that really caused the error, could that be the case? Had a similar problem once - you are Base64-encoding binary data there to construct the URL. This works often, but not always: as soon as the encoding contains a `+` you're likely to run into trouble, the `+` would have to be URL-encoded.